# Instabot KeyError: 'urlgen'

Tags: python, cookies, keyerror

im trying to do a instagram bot but i just could run the code once, and it worked fine but when i tried again it dropped me this error
i wont write my user and pass in this question obviously haha

```
from instabot import *
session = Bot()
session.login(username = "myuser",
              password = "mypass")
```

and i get this error

```
2021-02-01 16:07:42,401 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/EQUIPO/Desktop/5 CUATRI/Phyton/Ejercicios Prueba/nsoe.py", line 3, in <module>
    session.login(username = "nota.niceplace",
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\instabot\bot\bot.py", line 443, in login
    if self.api.login(**args) is False:
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 240, in login
    self.load_uuid_and_cookie(load_cookie=use_cookie, load_uuid=use_uuid)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\instabot\api\api_login.py", line 354, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    self.cookie_dict["urlgen"]
KeyError: 'urlgen'
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to delete config folder which is automatically created by system when you run this code first time.
So you need to delete this folder every time before run your code.
This config folder is in same directory where your file is saved.

I had same problem and i am able to solve by this way.

Answer (score 3):

This code will fix everything automatically for you just change image name and path.

```
from instabot import Bot
import os
import shutil


def clean_up(i):
    dir = "config"
    remove_me = "imgs\{}.REMOVE_ME".format(i)
    # checking whether config folder exists or not
    if os.path.exists(dir):
        try:
            # removing it so we can upload new image
            shutil.rmtree(dir)
        except OSError as e:
            print("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))
    if os.path.exists(remove_me):
        src = os.path.realpath("imgs\{}".format(i))
        os.rename(remove_me, src)


def upload_post(i):
    bot = Bot()

    bot.login(username="your_username", password="your_password")
    bot.upload_photo("imgs/{}".format(i), caption="Caption for the post")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # enter name of your image bellow
    image_name = "img.jpg"
    clean_up(image_name)
    upload_post(image_name)
```

Comment: Maybe add a short description of why this fixes his problem? :)

Comment: Ok no problem. First time you can run just upload_post() function and everything will work just fine, but at the end of first run in your folder some junk files will appear (config folder + renamed image you just posted) and if you try to run program again you will get an error. clean_up() function takes care of that, it checks if those junk files exist and deletes them before your next run of upload_post() function.  I don't know exact reason why those files appear and why they cause program to crash, for that information you will need to contact instabot creators :-)

Answer (score 1):

As Raj said. You need to delete the config folder like this from where you ran the python script. Sorry for making a separate answer but for me it was not immediate clear where this config folder was so I thought it might help.

```
rm -rf config
```

Unfortunately the library is quite poor with their error messages

Comment: I've been having the same problem, im trying to post an image every hour but the config file stop the code from working after the first run. But I cant delete it while the code is running because the config folder is being written into. Will your answer resolve my issue if I were to have a schedule 1 hour wait time between posts?

Comment: Yeah actually for me it also only works once. For now I just wrote a shell script that I run, of that first deletes the folder and then runs the script. But really not ideal. I still haven't figured out how you can keep using the bot without deleting the folder every time

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems that instabot library's maintenance is down, don't try to run anything using that lib, won't work, and might, as commented by some users, compromise your account! sorry..

Comment: is it still down? doesn't seem to be working, any other alternatives?