# AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'session'

Tags: python

Using Version: 0.117.0 of instabot.

Already being logged in I run:

```
from instabot import Bot
insta = Bot()
insta.upload_photo(photo_path,caption ="just try")
```

This is what I get:

```
2021-02-11 00:38:56,519 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
FOUND: w:1024 h:1024 r:1.0
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 43, in <module>
    insta.upload_photo(photo_path,caption ="just try")
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/bot/bot.py", line 806, in upload_photo
    return upload_photo(self, photo, caption, upload_id, from_video, options)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/bot/bot_photo.py", line 26, in upload_photo
    result = self.api.upload_photo(
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api/api.py", line 825, in upload_photo
    return upload_photo(
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api/api_photo.py", line 154, in upload_photo
    self.session.headers.update(
AttributeError: 'API' object has no attribute 'session'
```

Comment: *"Already being logged in"* — Perhaps not…? How do you figure that?

Comment: You were right. I was sure I had seen that the login was successful.

Comment: I updated my post to also include the answer since the question was marked closed

Comment: @Julian please post a new answer so your questions can look like it is solved

Comment: Just posted an answer after question was reopened

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can specify `use_cookie` parameter as `False` in `login()` method which means that bot would use cookies not to re-login every time it needs to push some request. Defaults as `True`.

```
bot.login(username="",password="",use_cookie=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

I already ran login before and it is supposed to store the credentials. When I reran login it always gave me:

```
2021-02-11 07:20:42,052 - INFO - Instabot version: 0.117.0 Started
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 42, in <module>
    insta.login(username=username,password=password)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/bot/bot.py", line 443, in login
    if self.api.login(**args) is False:
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api/api.py", line 240, in login
    self.load_uuid_and_cookie(load_cookie=use_cookie, load_uuid=use_uuid)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api/api.py", line 199, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    return load_uuid_and_cookie(self, load_uuid=load_uuid, load_cookie=load_cookie)
  File "/Users/user/.virtualenvs/v3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/instabot/api/api_login.py", line 354, in load_uuid_and_cookie
    self.cookie_dict["urlgen"]
KeyError: 'urlgen'
```

Which I thought was the feedback when you are already being logged in. I am still not sure why my first login seemed to fail. And why it doesn't give a proper feedback.
After dezese's answer I started doubting that the login was successful and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000898/instabot-keyerror-urlgen)
I just ended up running:

```
rm -rf config
```

And then the code properly with login:

```
insta = Bot()
insta.login(username=username,password=password)
insta.upload_photo(photo_path,caption ="just try")
```

And everything worked! Thanks deceze for pointing me in the right direction. I hope this detailed explanation helps people with similar issues, since those error codes are not really helpful in finding the true cause.

Currently I have to delete the config folder every time. Not the best solution but works for now. If anybody knows a better way please post it and I will accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by just deleting the `uuid_and_cookie.json` before `bot.login()`

```
import os
try:
    os.remove("config/<your_username>_uuid_and_cookie.json")
except:
    pass
```

There's a bug when the file exists