# How to delete files and folders in jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, runtime-error, instagram, delete-file

I've read all the other SO posts about this error:

`[WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process`

but for some reason still can't figure it out :( Including this tutorial:
https://python.tutorialink.com/python-winerror-32-the-process-cannot-access-the-file-because-it-is-being-used-by-another-process/#Answer

I'm trying to make a script that will send a msg to an instagram user. But apparently instabot creates a config folder every time you run the script and you have to delete that folder before you can run the script again. I'm trying to figure out how to automate that process.

I have this, but that's where I'm running into this error.

```
import os, shutil

for folder in ['config/log', 'config']:
    for filename in os.listdir(folder):
        file_path = os.path.join(folder, filename)
        try:
            if os.path.isfile(file_path) or os.path.islink(file_path):
                os.unlink(file_path)
            elif os.path.isdir(file_path):
                shutil.rmtree(file_path)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Failed to delete %s. Reason: %s' % (file_path, e))
```

I tried adding `os.chdir("C:/Users/xxxxx/")` as per the tutorial, but it's still not working. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: It doesn't make sense that you would have to delete the config folder, but the problem here seems pretty clear: someone (maybe you?) has an open handle to one of the files in that folder.  I suggest you try to make it work without this.

Comment: @TimRoberts yeah it's really weird. I get a "KeyError: 'ds_user'" error if the config folder isn't removed first. That was also a question on SO, that's how i learned that it needed to be deleted. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66000898/instabot-keyerror-urlgen I mean according to the tutorial, the script that's currently running is interfering with itself when trying to delete stuff, but i'm not sure how to get around that %\